# Merging mp4 video stream with subtitles for use in creating DVD

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

Suppose I have two files called `foo.mp4` and `foo.srt`. The mp4 file doesn't have subtitles, and I want to add subtitles from the `foo.srt` file.

The utility `mencoder` is frequently recommended in this context. I tried using, for example:

```
mencoder foo.mp4 -sub foo.srt -ovc lavc -oac copy -o foo.mpg
```

This worked for me before. However, here I get

```
Audio format 0x4134504d is incompatible with '-oac copy', please try '-oac pcm' instead or use '-fafmttag' to override it.
```

I don't know what this means. Running `mediainfo` on this file gives the following information for the `audio` stream.

```
Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1h 47mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 93.7 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 110 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 71.8 MiB (9%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-11-19 03:58:38
Tagged date                              : UTC 2014-11-19 03:58:40
```

Trying

```
mencoder foo.mp4 -sub foo.srt -ovc lavc -oac pcm -o foo.mpg
```

works, but produces a video that is visibly worse with regard to quality.

I suppose `ffmpeg` could also be an option, but I've not figured out how to use it to do this.

I'm using Debian wheezy. The versions of `mencoder` and `ffmpeg` that ship with wheezy are:

2:1.0~rc4.dfsg1+svn34540-1+deb7u1 (mencoder)

6:0.8.16-1 (ffmpeg)

However, I managed to backport a newer version of `ffmpeg` from unstable,
namely: `7:2.5.1-1`.

Comment: What output format do you want exactly? I see you used the AVI container in the question, but that doesn't tell me your desired video and audio formats.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Hi. The `avi` was a typo. The answer is, whatever I can eventually create a DVD with. This usually involves creating a DVD structure, and then an ISO from that. The first step involves creating a file from the original video file using `ffmpeg`, and I give this a `mpg` extension for reasons I'm not clear. After that this file is processed by `dvdauthor` to produce a directory structure, and then converted into an iso with `genisoimage`. So, I suppose that answer is, whatever formats work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`subtitles`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1) filter to create hardsubs ("burnt-in" subtitles):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf subtitles=subs.srt -target pal-dvd output.mpg
```

- `-target pal-dvd` will make the output have a frame rate of 25 and a frame size of 720x576. If you want NTSC output instead for a frame rate of 30000/1001 and frame size of 720x480, then use `-target ntsc-dvd`. For a frame rate of 24000/1001 and 720x480 frame size use `-target film-dvd`.
- The old, so-called "`ffmpeg`" version 0.8.16 in the repo is a counterfeit from a fork that lacks the `subtitles` filter. If you need the real thing you can simply [download a static build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).
- I do not believe `ffmpeg` can convert the text-based SRT to the bitmap-based dvdsub/vobsub, but there are probably other tools that can do so. This will allow you to use standard DVD subtitles which can be turned on or off by the viewer.

Comment: Thank you. That is very comprehensive. By "counterfeit"   I assume you mean that unfortunate fork? I think that the "7:2.5.1-1" is the real thing, correct? Would the result of `-target film-dvd` work on a regular DVD player?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I assume it is. If you run `ffmpeg`, the first line in the console output will tell you who developed it. If it displays `FFmpeg Developers` it is the real thing.

Comment: Also, is `mencoder` not a suitable tool for such a task? It seems to be widely recommended for doing such things on the net.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I believe development of `mencoder` has basically ceased some time ago, but if it works for you and you prefer it, go ahead and use it.

Comment: I'd certainly prefer to use something supported, but isn't mencoder part of mplayer? Why do you think mencoder development has ceased?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Looks like there has been ~14 commits to `mplayer.c` since 2012. Last commit was 2014-05-20. Not a perfect means of measurement, but that will give a good idea of activity. Looks like there have been ~7023 commits to FFmpeg since 2014-05-20. Also not a perfect measurement because that includes all commits to the whole project.

Comment: Do you mean `mencoder.c`, perhaps? I don't see an `mplayer.c` there. I cloned mplayer from svn. `svn info` gives "Repository Root: svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/mplayer". And `mencoder.c` has 10 commits since the beginning of 2013.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, that was a typo. Should have been `mencoder.c`, but the numbers remain the same.

Comment: We must be using different repositories. I have `2014-05-21` as the last commit, and it's definitely 10 commits since the beginning of 2013. But it doesn't really matter - I get your point.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Same repository. 10 commits since 2013 + 4 more since 2012 = 14.

Comment: Oh, you were talking about commits since the beginning of 2012. That was not clear to me. Then, yes, 14 commits since 1st January 2012. And yes, that isn't a lot of activity. Those maybe the software is mature/stable now. Dunno.